# Spawn and detach a "pwsh.exe" child process on Windows was not working

Tags: node.js, powershell-core

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const spawnOptions = { detached: true, stdio: 'ignore' }
const pwshProcess = spawn('pwsh.exe', [
   '-nop', '-nol', '-c', 'Set-Content -Path "D:\\outTest.txt" -Value "ok" -NoNewline'
], spawnOptions)

pwshProcess.unref()
process.exit()
```

File `D:\outTest.txt` will not create.
How to make the code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of test. I found a solution is using Windows Shell `start` command to create a new detachable process.

```
const { spawn, exec } = require('child_process')
const startPwshWindow = 'pwsh -nop -nol -noe'
const startPwshHidden = '/b pwsh -nop -nol -c Set-Content -Path ./outTest.txt -Value ok -NoNewline'
// using '/b' switch to create "no" new window

spawn('start', [startPwshWindow], {shell: true}).on('exit', process.exit)
exec(`start ${startPwshWindow}`).on('exit', process.exit)

spawn('start', [startPwshHidden], {shell: true}).on('exit', process.exit)
exec(`start ${startPwshHidden}`).on('exit', process.exit)
```

Answer (score 2):

This was the only way I could get this to work on Windows, but the spawned process is not detached. I tried manipulating the path to pwsh.exe, the working dir of the process, and different parameter combinations.

```bsh
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

const pwshProcess = spawn('pwsh.exe', [
    '-nop', '-nol', '-c', 'Set-Content -Path "./outTest.txt" -Value "ok" -NoNewline -Verbose;'
])

pwshProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

pwshProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(data.toString());
});

pwshProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});

// pwshProcess.unref()
// process.exit()
```

Spawning a detached `pwsh` process works as expected on Linux(Ubuntu):

```
const { spawn } = require
('child_process')
const spawnOptions = { detached: true, stdio: 'ignore' }
const pwshProcess = spawn('pwsh', [ 
    '-nop', '-nol', '-c', 'Set-Content -Path "outTest.txt" -Value "ok" -NoNewline -Verbose;'
], spawnOptions)
pwshProcess.unref()
process.exit()
```